# Printing specific output in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following array of arrays that represents a cycle in a graph that I want to print in the below format.

```
scala> result.collect

Array[Array[Long]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 4, 0), Array(1, 5, 2, 1), Array(1, 4, 0, 1), Array(2, 3, 5, 2), Array(2, 1, 5, 2), Array(3, 5, 2, 3), Array(4, 0, 1, 4), Array(5, 2, 3, 5), Array(5, 2, 1, 5))
```

```
0:0->1->4;
1:1->5->2;1->4->0;
2:2->3->5;2->1->5;
3:3->5->2;
4:4->0->1;
5:5->2->3;5->2->1;
```

How can I do this? I have tried to do a for loop with if statements like other coding languages but scala's ifs in for loops are for filtering and cannot make use if/else to account for two different criteria.

example python code

```
for (array,i) in enumerate(range(0,result.length)):
    if array[i] == array[i+1]:
        //print thing needed
    else:
       // print other thing
```

I also tried to do result.groupBy to make it easier to print but doing that ruins the arrays.

```
Array[(Long, Iterable[Array[Long]])] = Array((4,CompactBuffer([J@3677a08a)), (0,CompactBuffer([J@695fd7e)), (1,CompactBuffer([J@50b0f441, [J@142efc4d)), (3,CompactBuffer([J@1fd66db2)), (5,CompactBuffer([J@36811d3b, [J@61c4f556)), (2,CompactBuffer([J@2eba1b7, [J@2efcf7a5)))
```

Is there a way to nicely print the output needed in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```scala
result
  .groupBy(_.head)
  .toArray
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .map {
    case (node, cycles) =>
      val paths = cycles.map { cycle =>
        cycle
          .init // drop last node
          .mkString("->")
      }

      s"$node:${paths.mkString(";")}"
  }
  .mkString(";\n")
```

This is the output for the sample input you provided:

```
0:0->1->4;
1:1->5->2;1->4->0;
2:2->3->5;2->1->5;
3:3->5->2;
4:4->0->1;
5:5->2->3;5->2->1
```